# Syntax to resolve ORACLE error is ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the NVL function to try and correct

**ERROR: Error fetching from cursor. ORACLE error is ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero.**

I'm having trouble figuring out what the correct syntax is.

```
(nvl(sum(case when t.LABEL in (12,14,24,25,26,33) and t.sales_credit=1 then t.AMOUNT else 0 end),0) / nvl(sum(case when t.sales_credit=1 then t.AMOUNT else 0 end),0))*100 as DOLSHAR_COR_M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal method is `nullif()` in the dividend.  So, instead of:

```
nvl(sum(case when t.sales_credit=1 then t.AMOUNT else 0 end), 0))
```

You would use:

```
nullif(sum(case when t.sales_credit=1 then t.AMOUNT else 0 end), 0))
```

Assuming that `t.Amount` is never negative or `0`, it is sufficient to just drop the `else 0`:

```
sum(case when t.sales_credit = 1 then t.AMOUNT end)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your query or syntax. Just change the logic of replacing null with 0.

The divisor can not be 0. so you need to use 1 instead, as follows:

```
SELECT
    ( NVL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN T.LABEL IN(
            12, 14, 24, 25, 26, 33
        )
             AND T.SALES_CREDIT = 1 THEN T.AMOUNT
        ELSE 0
    END), 0) / 
    NVL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN T.SALES_CREDIT = 1   THEN T.AMOUNT
        ELSE 0
    END), 1 /*0*/) ) * 100 AS DOLSHAR_COR_M -- change here to avoid /0 error -- used 1 instead of 0
from DUAL;
```

I think it has no records for which SUM executes and making the whole expression as null.

Cheers!!